# Required app screenshots and app-previews for non-universal apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

I was asked (in June 2021) to update my app on the App-Store. So I prepare the app-update and also prepare the updated entry in appstore-connect.

The app I am upgrading is a non-universal app, in my case this means, it is designed for iPhones only. (Of course iPads can handle iPhone apps as well.)

So I add the screenshots and previews for the 6.5 and the 5.5 inch iPhone displays. For now I can still see both iPad display size tabs (12.9 inch for 2nd and 3rd Gen. of iPads). Both of those tabs ar currently empty, because I don't intend to create this sort of screenshots and previews.
*(The tabs also exist after I upload the app to appstore-connect using XCode, and select the new build. I was probably expecting, the tabs would go away, as soon as the appstore-connect realizes that the new build is for iPhones only - but no, they are still there.)*

**Will this work to submit or will Apple reject it directly, asking for iPad screenshots and previews as well?**

I asked Apple the same question trough the resolution center, but they only send me the link to the whole App-Store guidance. And I did not really find this specific information.

Has anyone experience with this kind of issue?

PS: 3 years ago, as I initially released the app, I only added the 5.5 inch screenshots and previews and it was okay.

Comment: You only need the iPhone images

Comment: @Paulw11: this is correct, Apple accepted it without any issue. Consider you to answer this question, so I can vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need the iPhone images, since it is non universal. I have published several non universal apps and they have all been approved by Apple.